# Signal module does not raise exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, signals

I am trying to learn python's signal module. Please consider the example below:

```
def timeoutFn(func, args=(), kwargs={}, timeout_duration=1, default=None):
     import signal

     class TimeoutError(Exception):
         pass

     def handler(signum, frame):
         print "Trying to raise exception"
         raise TimeoutError

     # set the timeout handler
     signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
     signal.alarm(timeout_duration)
     try:
         result = func(*args, **kwargs)
     except TimeoutError as exc:
         result = default
     finally:   
         signal.alarm(0)

     return result
```

and,

```
import time

def foo():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print "Sleeping"
```

On calling the function `timeoutFn(foo)` the following gets printed but it does raise the exception.

Shouldn't it raise the TimeoutError? But, all it prints is

`Sleeping
Trying to raise exception`
and program stops.

Comment: It works correct. What do you expect? That exception been raised?

Comment: After printing "Trying to raise exception", I don't get any TimeoutError

Answer (score 0):

The exception has not been raised, because you catch it. Pay attention to the line:

```
 except TimeoutError as exc:
     result = default
```

The block means, that if the exception TimeoutError had been raised, `result` will be assigned to `default` (which is `None` in your example) and the scripts continues further without showing an exception.

**Update:**

`signal.alarm` doesn't stop the flow. So the exception will be raised by timeout and if the script will be by that time in a try block, than the exception will be caught. You can see better how does it work if you increase `timeout_duration` to 3. Than there will be more time to print several 'sleep' messages. It shows, that by the time when the exception is raised, the interpreter had entered the try block.

Comment: This line catches the exception that occurs in 'try' block, not the exception occuring before try.

Comment: `signal.alarm` doesn't stops the flow. So the exception will be raised by timeout and if the script will be in a try block, than the exception will be caught. You can see better how does it work if you increase `timeout_duration` to 3. Than there will be more time to print several 'sleep' messages.